# upgrade kills internet connection;how to fix?

Tags: networking, 18.04

After online upgrade from 16 to 18 I have no internet. Shows as connected but can't connect. How can I fix this please? I have tried the various help pages from a live OS, but with no success. I tried to print a promising thread without success. Obviously no point in sending "C&P" instructions either. I have loaded another install but I am running out of space. Help, please.